# Only stories are showing in board in JIRA. I want all Epics, Stories, Tasks, Sub-taks to see in board

Tags: jira

In JIRA Board, only "stories" are showing

Filter for JIRA from (vertical3 dot > Board setting > General > Filter > Edit Filter Query)

```
project = NAP ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

Here I can see all the EPICS, STORIES, SUB-TASKS. I tried to change it to

```
project = NAP AND issuetype in (standardIssueTypes(), subTaskIssueTypes()) ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

NAP is project name

But, it is also same only. As standardIssueTypes(Bug, Epic, Story, Tasks) & subTaskIssueTypes(Sub-tasks), together is ALL

But, when I am going to board, it is still showing only "stories"